# Where is OpenVPN's sacli?

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to setup a Windows client and I need sacli in Ubuntu to create the client configuration file. Does anyone know where it is? I cant find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `sacli` [is not packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=sacli).

You can download the OpenVPN Access Server from [Download page](https://openvpn.net/download-open-vpn/). Then install it to your system with:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget https://swupdate.openvpn.org/as/openvpn-as-2.7.3-Ubuntu16.amd_64.deb
  sudo apt install ./openvpn-as-2.7.3-Ubuntu16.amd_64.deb # for 16.04 LTS
  ```
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget https://openvpn.net/downloads/openvpn-as-latest-ubuntu18.amd_64.deb
  sudo apt install ./openvpn-as-latest-ubuntu18.amd_64.deb
  ```

and then launch `sacli` with

```
/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the info, will do.

Comment: This get me the error  OpenVPN-as Depends openvpn-as-bundled-clients but it is not installable

Comment: @FidelOrozco then its third-party packaging issue. Ask OpenVPN support about this.